How to make vitest fail fast after first known test failure
I am using Vitest for testing and would like it to fail fast upon first error. The reason is that I'm using it within git bisect and don't need to waste time on the whole test run once there is an error.
I haven’t found an equivalent in Vitest. How can I configure Vitest or work around this to achieve similar functionality?

https://vitest.dev/guide/cli#bail?

@jonrsharpe thanks indeed, found it quite quickly but having a Q&A here will make it more easily discoverable via Google search "vitest fail fast"

The option is called --bail, passing --bail=1 makes vitest fail after first failure:
vitest --bail=1

From the docs:

bail
Type: number
Default: 0
CLI: --bail=<value>
Stop test execution when given number of tests have failed.
By default Vitest will run all of your test cases even if some of them
fail. This may not be desired for CI builds where you are only
interested in 100% successful builds and would like to stop test
execution as early as possible when test failures occur. The bail
option can be used to speed up CI runs by preventing it from running
more tests when failures have occurred.
from https://vitest.dev/config/#bail

